# Android- How to implement Horizontal Step Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-xml, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

I want to implement horizontal progress bar with steps like shown in following img.

[image: Horizontal Step Progress bar]

I could not find such native component in Android. Can anyone guide me on how to do it ?

Comment: You need to implement custom view extends ProgressBar

Comment: hm.. is tht the only way ? and if yes.. any links that may be useful ?

Comment: take a look how to create custom views http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html aslo lookt at progress bar source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java?av=f and simple custom progress bar with text http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/23/android-progressbar-with-text/

Comment: use a range bar. look at this link https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar or https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT: A repo which seems to currently be well supported and used (Sep 2016)** https://github.com/baoyachi/StepView

[image: StepView]

*Old Answer:*

This answer is late to the party, but so far the best I've found is this repo from Anton46: https://github.com/anton46/Android-StepsView
It's quite simple to setup too.

Heres an example:

[image]

Comment: Accepted the answer. Back in the days when question was asked, there was no such library present. :) Thanks for putting a light on this question.

Comment: No problem @rohit, I've actually found a better supported repo, Ive added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot

Comment: Width not increse when we user vertical  Please improve when data is more data is overlapping other view

Answer (score 12):

I found a [Vertical Steper](https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/vertical-stepper-form) that follows Google Material Design guidelines:

[image]

And also another well documented library [Here](https://github.com/kofigyan/StateProgressBar)

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Can I add recyclerview for content in vertical stepper?

Answer (score 2):

I've created a Step View ViewPager that supports both Horizontal and Vertical paging and doesn't require drawables and images. You can configure the appearance by simply specifying various attributes.

It can be found here https://github.com/YablokovDmitry/StepViewPager

[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]

[image: Sample 3]