# How to create a step view in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider

How can I create a step view like this?

[image: Wizard Progress Step view]

Is it possible to create this using only one drawable and filling that drawable for a certain amount? Where each amount represents a step. 
So in step 4/5, it's filled for 80%.

I want to use it in my Slider Activity which I created using this tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide

If anyone could give advice on this, that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: How about using **`Seekbar`**  or a **`ProgressBar`** also  Check this [Android How to Build Intro Slider for your App](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/)

Comment: You can go with ProgressBar

Comment: @NileshRathod I just want to display something to the user, it doesn't need to be editable like the slider/seekbar

Comment: @PapanManna Can i just set the progress of the progressbar in the code? Can i also set a custom shape for the progressbar?

Comment: @PetervanLeeuwen yes you can disable **`seekbar`** to take input from user check this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27779040/7666442

Comment: One more library with customizable appearance https://stackoverflow.com/a/56424619/11561980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to implement step view using ProgressBar. Check the following link then implement your own.

[VerticalStepperForm](https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/VerticalStepperForm)

[StateProgressBar](https://github.com/kofigyan/StateProgressBar)

Comment: I have also googled and I have seen those. But they are not according to the design, which you can find in my question.

Comment: These are just for example. You can achieve the above StepView using ProgressBar. You can set custom drawable background and set progress on the ProgressBar.

Comment: you can check this example also. https://www.journaldev.com/9629/android-progressbar-example

Comment: Great! I first used seekbar, but that is not needed. A basic progressbar is just fine. Thanks for helping me.